# AngularJS - ng-show in Bootstrap popover in Razor

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a list of buttons that represent a folder hierarchy on my db. When clicked I want a Bootstrap popover to appear with icon buttons for adding new folders, removing folders, changing hierarchy, etc. However, AngularJS doesn't work in the popover, causing ng-click and ng-show to no longer work. Here's a button:

```
<button type="button" id="0" ng-click="selectFolder($event)" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="Bewerk folder" data-content="@popoverContent">@ViewBag.Title</button>

var popoverContent = "";
popoverContent += "<button type='button' id='newHierarchy' class='btn btn-success' ng-click='addHierarchy = !addHierarchy'>";
popoverContent += new Icon("plus").Html;
popoverContent += "</button>";
popoverContent += "<input type='text' id='newHierarchyName' class='form-control' name='newHierarchyName' ng-show='addHierarchy' />";
```

I found some similar questions whose answer all involved directives. However, I don't understand how I should implement a directive in my case.

Comment: I was going to say something on the lines of what you've already read elsewhere. Some links that can help you:
http://nohros.com/nsPopover/
Also check out the popover @ http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @Chinmay thank you for pointing in the right direct, I am now using Angular UI